# Array will not output in div

Tags: javascript

SOLVED!
I am trying to output my array values in a div on my website.
But it only write the last element in the array. In the console it write all the values in right order etc. But it will not show on the website. 
This is my code:

```
var temp_array = [''];
var filename = [
        'Teknisk Broschyr 35A',
        'Teknisk Data 35A',
        'Drift och skötsel 35A',
        'Mått och montering 35A',
        'Elschema 35A'
        ];
function writename(checkboxElem, id){
        var compare = id;
        if(checkboxElem.checked)
        {
            temp_array.push(filename[compare]);
        }
        else{
            var index = temp_array.indexOf(filename[compare]);
            if (index > -1) {
                temp_array.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
        for(i = 0; i < temp_array.length; i++)
        {
            //console.log(temp_array.length);
            console.log(temp_array[i]);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += temp_array[i];
        }
    }
```

Thankfull for help.

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = temp_array[i];` because you overwrite `innerHTML` with every iteration. At the end you have the last element shown only. You could do `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += temp_array[i];`

Comment: I tried that, but then it just added every change multiple times like:
Teknisk Broschyr 35A
Teknisk Broschyr 35ATeknisk Data 35A
etc...

Answer (score 1):

@kuben,
Inside forloop  you are overriding **document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML**  the value with the current value, so at end its displaying the last element.
Replace your code 
 `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = temp_array[i];`

with

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += temp_array[i];
```

Check this,

```
var temp_array = [''];
var filename = [
        'Teknisk Broschyr 35A',
        'Teknisk Data 35A',
        'Drift och skötsel 35A',
        'Mått och montering 35A',
        'Elschema 35A'
        ];
    function writename(checkboxElem, id){
        var compare = id;
        if(checkboxElem.checked)
        {
            temp_array.push(filename[compare]);
        }
        else{
            var index = temp_array.indexOf(filename[compare]);
            if (index > -1) {
                temp_array.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < temp_array.length; i++)
        {
            //console.log(temp_array.length);
            console.log(temp_array[i]);

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += temp_array[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var temp_array = [''];
var filename = [
    'Teknisk Broschyr 35A',
    'Teknisk Data 35A',
    'Drift och skötsel 35A',
    'Mått och montering 35A',
    'Elschema 35A'
];

function writename(checkboxElem, id) {
    var compare = id;
    if (checkboxElem.checked) {
        temp_array.push(filename[compare]);
    } else {
        var index = temp_array.indexOf(filename[compare]);
        if (index > -1) {
            temp_array.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML='';//clear the history result;
    for (i = 0; i < temp_array.length; i++) {
        //console.log(temp_array.length);
        console.log(temp_array[i]);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += temp_array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but I get a pyramid-list like:
Value1
Value1Vlaue2
Value1Value2Value3...

Comment: @Kuben i guess you use writename like a onclick callback,so try again,have updated the code.if not work,better give me a demo.

Comment: Found a sultoion, I had to empty the div before I loop through the array :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: ,,,,that equals to my updated answer,,,you must use the writename as a callback when triggered